# Component is not appearing on button click with the data fetched by API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

What I am Trying to do is to fetch data from a Weather API on button click and when the data is fetched then that data should be mapped inside a component (i.e. Weather) and then only that component should appear on the screen, right now I am able to fetch the data but even then the component is not appearing.

**Container.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './container.css'
import Weather from './weather';
class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            location: "",
            weather: []
        };
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
    }

    continue = (e) => {

        const { location } = this.state;
        const rawurl = 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=d8fefab56305f5a343b0eab4f837fec1&query=' + location;
        const url = rawurl;
        //e.preventDefault();
        if (location.length < 1) {
            return alert('Enter the details');
        }
        else {
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data =>{
                        this.setState({weather:data});
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log("error ",err)) 
        }
    };
    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        const weather =
        this.state.weather.length> 0 ? 
        this.state.weather.map(item => (<Weather location={item.location.name} temperature={item.current.temperature} weather={item.current.weather_descriptions[0]} windSpeed={item.current.wind_speed} windDegree={item.current.wind_degree} windDir={item.current.wind_dir} humidity={item.current.humidity} visibility={item.current.visibility} />
            ))
        :<span></span>
        return (
            <div id="container">
                <div class="searchicon">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Enter City !!" type="text" name="location" value={this.state.location} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    <label class="icon">
                        <button onClick={this.continue}><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                {weather}
                </div>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Container;
```

**Weather.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';

class Weather extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div id="result">
                <div id="location" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Location
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                        {this.props.location}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Temperature" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Temperature
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.temperature}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Weather" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Weather
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.weather}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Windspeed" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Wind Speed
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.windSpeed}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Wind_degree" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Wind Degree
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.windDegree}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Wind_dir" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Wind Direction
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.windDir}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Humidity" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Humidity
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.humidity}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Visibility" class="insideres">
                    <div class="title">
                        Visibility
                    </div>
                    <div class="res">
                    {this.props.visibility}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );    
    }
}
export default Weather;
```

I want this weather component to appear when the data is fetched from the API, but right now data is being fetched but its not appearing.

[image]

In the above image you can see I am getting data from API, but not getting Weather component with that data under searchbar.

Comment: Probably weather object is not an array, maybe you should log the data you received from the API, and find the weather data you want, maybe what you should do is this.setState({weather:data.data}); , but log the data you receive first and find which part you want

Comment: its an array, and I am getting data on fetching, but the component Weather is not appearing with the data fetched.

Comment: as I can see from the screenshot, the weather is not an array, so could you please show the weather object you logged

Comment: @AliAbuHijleh weather is array, i have printed the whole state there

Comment: I see that it's an object not an array, recheck it

Comment: @AliAbuHijleh look in image, can u see, that Array(0), should it appear for object or Array?

Comment: yes, initially it was an array, but after you fetched the data, it becomes an object { }

Comment: so what to do now, how can I solve the problem, can you give solution @AliAbuHijleh

Comment: on this.setState({weather:data.data}); i m getting undefined

Comment: Ok so first log this console.log(this.state.weather);, and show me the data inside

Comment: current: {observation_time: "12:18 AM", temperature: 28, weather_code: 143, weather_icons: Array(1), weather_descriptions: Array(1), …}
location: {name: "Jaipur", country: "India", region: "Rajasthan", lat: "26.917", lon: "75.817", …}
request: {type: "City", query: "Jaipur, India", language: "en", unit: "m"}
__proto__: Object

Comment: current:
cloudcover: 50
feelslike: 31
humidity: 94
is_day: "no"
observation_time: "12:18 AM"
precip: 0
pressure: 1000
temperature: 28
uv_index: 1
visibility: 3
weather_code: 143
weather_descriptions: Array(1)
0: "Mist"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
weather_icons: Array(1)
0: "https://assets.weatherstack.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0006_mist.png"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
wind_degree: 0
wind_dir: "N"
wind_speed: 0
__proto__: Object
location:
country: "Ind

Comment: Could you expand the object weather you receive in the log screenshot, because I can't read it in this way, what is current?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update to your component using react with hooks. I highly suggest you adopt this pattern as it is way easier to work with, but does require using React 16 if you haven't adopted this yet. You will notice that I:

- am using template strings instead of concatenating strings. This is best practice.
- use async/await with promises
- using an if statement to render the Weather component if the length of the weather variable in state is greater than 0. If it isn't, it will render the container component.

```
import "./container.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";

import Weather from "./weather";

const Container = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

    const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
        const url = `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=d8fefab56305f5a343b0eab4f837fec1&query=${location}`;
        if (location.length < 1) {
            return alert("Enter the details");
        } else {
            await fetch(url)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    setWeather(data);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log("error ", err));
        }
    };

    if (weather.length > 0) {
        return weather.map((item) => (
            <Weather
                location={item.location.name}
                temperature={item.current.temperature}
                weather={item.current.weather_descriptions[0]}
                windSpeed={item.current.wind_speed}
                windDegree={item.current.wind_degree}
                windDir={item.current.wind_dir}
                humidity={item.current.humidity}
                visibility={item.current.visibility}
            />
        ));
    }

    return (
        <div id="container">
            <div className="searchicon">
                <input
                    placeholder="Enter City !!"
                    type="text"
                    name="location"
                    value={location}
                    onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                />
                <label className="icon">
                    <button onClick={fetchWeatherData}>
                        <span className="fa fa-search" />
                    </button>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>{weather}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Container;
```

Comment: getting this error ->      Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {request, location, current}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at container.jsx:56)
    in div (at container.jsx:41)
    in Container (at App.js:11)
    in div (at App.js:9)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)

Comment: That is probably the div at the end of container with {weather} in it. I suggest removing that or mapping the weather array into components. Remember to follow the lines in the errors it gives you in the error to debug.